# What is the right way to show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n) = f(x), x_n \to x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

There is a question (could be from Ruddin's real analysis text)

[image]

To show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n) = f(x)$, is equivalent to show that:

$$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$

Which of the following approach is the correct way to show the above?

1. $|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f(x)|$

We know $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ since $f$ converges uniformly, we know $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ because continuous function preserves convergence, hence $|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

or

2. $|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - f(x)|$

We have $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| < \epsilon$ by uniform convergence, and $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ by continuity, thus $|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

Which of the above method is the right way to prove the problem?

Comment: @Cameron Williams That's just the other way around. What you state there is pointwise convergence. Actually, the second way is the right one and the first is flawed. You only have to be a little more careful with the n's and $\varepsilon$'s.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp You're right. I was thinking of the internal limit on the $x_n$, when I should have been thinking of the external limit on the $f_n$. The lack of quantifiers messed me up. Good catch!

Comment: @CameronWilliams@FriedrichPhilipp So what is wrong with the first one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is correct as mentioned in the comments.

There is a flaw in the argument of the first approach.

That $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in E$ when $n$ is sufficiently large is clear.  However you need to show that there exists $N(\epsilon,x) \in \mathbb{N},$ depending only on $\epsilon$ and $x$, such that if $n > N(\epsilon,x)$ we have $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$. Continuity of $f_n$ is not sufficient at this point.  You only can argue that for fixed $m$ we have $f_m(x_n) \to f_m(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.

If the sequence $(f_n)$ is *equicontinuous* then there exists $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that $|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n$ when $|y-x| < \delta(\epsilon)$.  Since $x_n \to x$, we can choose $N(\epsilon,x)$ such that $|x_n - x| < \delta(\epsilon)$ for $n > N(\epsilon,x)$ it follows that $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

As it turns out the uniform convergence of $f_n$ on $E$ -- even if it is not compact -- guarantees equicontinuity, but this is harder to prove than the proposition in the problem using your second approach.

**Addendum**

Here is a specific example to show that you cannot argue that $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)| \to 0$ using only that $f_n$ is continuous and "... continuous function preserves convergence."

Consider the sequence of continuous functions where $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$.  Suppose $x_n = 1 - 1/n.$

Then $x_n \to 1$, but

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n(x_n) - f_n(1)| = \lim_{n \to \infty}|(1 - 1/n)^n - 1| = |e^{-1} - 1| \neq 0.$$

In this case, of course, the sequence of functions is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Hi could you provide a formal statement on your last claim on equicontinuity and perhaps direct me to a proof of sorts :) thank you!

Comment: Best to start here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/81396/148510

Comment: I noticed that you write $N(\epsilon, x)$ and $\delta(\epsilon)$. Is it good practice to put stuff into $N$ and $\delta$ like that?

Comment: Sure -- I think it helps avoid confusion. We have pointwise convergence $1/(xn) \to 0$ on $(0,1)$ because if $ n > N(\epsilon,x) = \lceil 1/(\epsilon x) \rceil$ then $|1/(nx)| < \epsilon$.